# How to convert a range of columns from Character to Number/Integer in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am tryin to convert a few columns which are in a range from Character to Integer. I dont want to write each column `as.integer`.

I am trying to find a more effective way where I can pass the the column names which I want to convert and then convert them into integer.

Is this doable in R? Or Should I do it one column after the other.

The Expected output:

1. Convert a range of data which is in char to Integer.
2. Convert a few columns without using passing them as range but rather as individual columns.

The code I wrote is given below:

```
library(readxl)

Final <- read_excel("C:/X/X/X- X/Desktop/Final.xlsx")

First_Date <- colnames(Final)[4]
Last_Date <- tail(colnames(Final),1)

str(Final)

Final <- Final %>% 
  mutate_if(c(First_Date:Last_Date),as.numeric)
```

The data I am working with is given below:

```
structure(list(UniqueID = c("3F-FA|807905", "3F-FA|808005", "3F-FA|808006", 
"3F-FA|808007", "Py_AuAriFa|761403", "3F-FA|761502", "AutoTheta|761602", 
"3F-FA|318901", "3F-FA|339401"), Xreg = c("3F-FA", "3F-FA", "3F-FA", 
"3F-FA", "Py_AuAriFa", "3F-FA", "AutoTheta", "3F-FA", "3F-FA"
), Row = c("807905", "808005", "808006", "808007", "761403", 
"761502", "761602", "318901", "339401"), `2023-02-01` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "50", "1", "7", "0", "0"), `2023-03-01` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "32", "1", "7", "0", "0"), `2023-04-01` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "36", "1", "7", "0", "0"), `2023-05-01` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "41", "1", "7", "0", "0"), `2023-06-01` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "31", "1", "6", "0", "0"), `2023-07-01` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "38", "1", "6", "0", "0"), `2023-08-01` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "34", "1", "6", "0", "0"), `2023-09-01` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "32", "1", "6", "0", "0"), `2023-10-01` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "35", "1", "5", "0", "0")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

The columns I am trying to convert is from 2023-02-01 to 2023-10-01. I cant use `mutateif` and pass it through the whole dataframe as the column `Row` has data which are character and can be converted to integer but should not be converted. Hence the selected few columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can match the patterns in the column names to loop over those column and modify the class

```
library(dplyr)
Final <- Final %>% 
       mutate(across(matches("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$"), as.integer))
```

Or use the `:`

```
Final <- Final %>%
    mutate(across("2023-02-01":"2023-10-01", as.integer))
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you. But Is it possible to pass this through a variable rather than mentioning the column dates? If so can you please tell me how to do the same?